# Query a mongodb record comparing values in an array to the array passed in the query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document in the format

```
{
"history": [
{
  "plugin": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
  ]
},
{
  "plugin": [
    2,
    3,
    4,
    6
  ]
},
{
  "plugin": [
    1,
    4
  ]
}
]
}
```

and i have an array x =[2,7],

I want query in such a way that if there is atleast one element in x which match with any of the element in the the plugin array, it should be return

thus for this case the expected result is

```
{
"history": [
{
  "plugin": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
  ]
},
{
  "plugin": [
    2,
    3,
    4,
    6
  ]
}    
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following pipeline which uses the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)** operator to return a subset of the `history` array that passes a given specified condition. This condition makes use of the **[`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/#exp._S_setIntersection)** set operator to check the embedded `plugin` array if it intersects with the given input comparison array.

So for instance, the expression

```
{ $setIntersection: [ [ 1, 4 ],  [ 2, 7 ] ] }
```

will return an empty set (array `[]`) since the two arrays do not intersect. Use this as basis to compare the result with the **[`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/ne/#exp._S_ne)** comparison operator. This will return `true` when the compared two values are not equivalent and `false` when they are equivalent. Use this result to feed the "cond" expression so that it will filter the appropriate elements.

The following pipeline demonstrates this:

```
var arr = [2,7];
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId("57ffe28591f567293497d924") } },  // <-- filter here      
    {
        "$project": {
            "history": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$history",
                    "as": "item",
                    "cond": {
                        "$ne": [
                            { "$setIntersection": ["$$item.plugin", arr] },
                            []
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ffe28591f567293497d924"),
    "history" : [ 
        {
            "plugin" : [ 
                1, 
                2, 
                3, 
                4
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "plugin" : [ 
                2, 
                3, 
                4, 
                6
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

As an alternative solution (if your MongoDB version does not support the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)** operator), consider using a combination of the **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** and **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operators to return the filtered array:

```
var arr = [2,7];
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId("57ffe28591f567293497d924") } },  // <-- filter here      
    {
        "$project": {
            "history": {
                 "$setDifference": [
                    {
                        "$map": {
                            "input": "$history",
                            "as": "item",
                            "in": {
                                "$cond": [
                                    {
                                        "$ne": [
                                            { "$setIntersection": ["$$item.plugin", arr] },
                                            []
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "$$item",
                                    false
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    [false]
                 ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: How do I add another condition to match the '_id'

Comment: @JibinMathew I've added the filter, check out the updated answer.

Comment: the solution works only for mongo 3.2 , but the mongo i am using is 3.0.4

Comment: @JibinMathew Check updated answer for an alternative.

Comment: if for some record in the array if the key plugin doesn't exist, that also gets returned returned, which shouldn't be the case

Comment: You would have to include the expression [**`$ifNull`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) in your `$cond` operator.